# Getting ACME error when going for new domain cert

Tags: lets-encrypt, traefik

I am sure I am doing something stupid here, but I have been going around in circles for a bit.  I have `Traefik` up and running with a cert for `url1.ccsilab.com`.  I am trying to add for `url1.ccsicloudsolutions.com` that goes to the same place.  I tried with two frontends pointing to one backend and now I have two frontends each pointing to their own identical backend.  I am getting the following error.

> Oct  3 16:15:30 ip-10-230-0-10 traefik[27166]: {“level”:“error”,“msg”:“Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains \“ccsicloudsolutions.com,url1.ccsicloudsolutions.com\” : unable to generate a certificate for the domains [ccsicloudsolutions.com url1.ccsicloudsolutions.com]: acme: Error -\u003e One or more domains had a problem:\n[ccsicloudsolutions.com] acme: Error 403 - urn:ietf:params:acme:error:unauthorized - Invalid response from http://ccsicloudsolutions.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/UoyASm_w_5Xkdv-xVx8NKi3ndbZ81tls_0eHO8iAD0I [34.194.40.15]: 404\n”,“time”:“2018-10-03T16:15:30Z”}

Below is the acme portion of the config:

```
[acme]
email = “xxxx@yyy.com”
storage = “acme.json”
caServer = “https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory”
entryPoint = “https”
 [acme.httpChallenge]
 entryPoint = “http”

[[acme.domains]]
 main = “ccsilab.com”
 sans = [“url1.ccsilab.com”]

[[acme.domains]]
 main = “ccsicloudsolutions.com”
 sans = [“url1.ccsicloudsolutions.com”]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the domain `ccsicloudsolutions.com` doesn't points to traefik or access to the resource which Let's Encrypt's verification server requested, requires authentication (Error 403).

Make sure the DNS records for the domain are correct and that the `http` entrypoint doesn't require authentication.

This error message comes up, when Let's Encrypt fails to verify the ownership of the domain.

---

Also, I'd use the new Let's Encrypt endpoint (`https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`)